# Method overriding as a substitution for instanceof in Java?

Tags: design

In short, is `instanceof` a bad thing?

I had a code something like

```java
Converted convert(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof ClassA) {
        convert((ClassA) o);
    }
    if (o instanceof ClassB) {
        convert((ClassB) o);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(o.class + " not suported");
}
```

I didn't realize it can be in fact refactored to

```java
Converted convert(Object o) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(o.class + " not suported");
}
Converted convert(ClassA a) {
    // do the conversion for ClassA
}
Converted convert(ClassB b) {
    // do the conversion for ClassB
}
```

ClassA and ClassB are some generated classes without common interface so I cannot do a conversion in one method (without reflection as the method names I'm interested in are the same in ClassA and ClassB).

On the other hand I do not really see a benefit of implementing it that way.

Additionally (when same principe is applied), I'm working with JSF and I have several implementations of `javax.faces.convert.Converter`, for example

```java
@Component
public class CountryConverter implements Converter {

    @Autowired
    private CountryServiceImpl countryService;

    @Override
    public CountryDto getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return countryService.findById(Long.parseLong(value));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value instanceof CountryDto) {
            Long id = ((CountryDto) value).getId();
            return Long.toString(id);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

...I can have very similarly

```java
    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, CountryDto country) {
        return country.getId();
    }
```

where overloaded version with Object can be in some common parent, but it all seems to me as overengineering = as I mentioned I see no benefit of doing it that way, just because I can. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) is a principle I like and implementation with `instanceof` is straightforward...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacement for instanceof Java?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184109/replacement-for-instanceof-java)

Comment: @gnat Thanks, I'll read that for sure, I found also this one before asking - [Avoiding instanceof in Java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/342072/avoiding-instanceof-in-java) I need some time to think about it still...

Comment: Your refactored examples where you put the type into the method arguments are NOT equivalent! Those are method overloads, and the compiler selects one based on the type of *variables* at compile time (assuming that no reflection is involved). In contrast, instanceof always checks the type of the *object* at run time.

Comment: Method overloading doesn't work the way you think it does.

Answer (score 7):

Using `instanceof` isn't per se the problem, but it's generally an indicator of a problem where you're explicitly testing an instance's type in order to define behavior.  This goes against Liskov's Substitution Principle which states that you should be dealing with an interface or abstract class which can be handled in the same manner throughout your program indifferently of how the concrete class implements it.

Of course I say "generally" because sometimes through the way some libraries such as jsf work, you're given an Object instance, and rather than simply cast it to the class which it *should* be, you perform a "sanity check" and you test its type anyway.  This is to say, use `instanceof` to check an instance's type because if it isn't this type, we're in a fubar situation here.

If you require your converter class to handle ClassA and ClassB, then unless you can find traits similar to both and create an interface in common with both, you should be creating two separate converter classes, one for ClassA and another for ClassB.  It seems like overengineering, but when the alternative is to use `instanceof` to determine type information to know how to handle it, then I would argue that two single-responsibility classes is *simpler* than one which awkwardly handles both.

Comment: Well, but to get an instance of a converted for ClassA/ClassB I have to have somewhere a factory method or something, that would know which converter to use based on type... Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Betlista The converter should be configured in your jsf configuration pertaining to a specific type.  Simply have a second converter, one to handle ClassA and one to handle ClassB.

Comment: I have to revisit the idea of shared converter, but I'm afraid it was kind of a shortcut... The JSF converteris clear, on JSF page it is specified, which one to use. Other one (first one) is not on view layer, but service layer... But here my team mates took different approach as technology was not forcing them to have it separated.

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` is bad because it forces the *user* of a set of classes to be aware of all the different subclasses that you invent.

As it is, whenever a new subclass is written, classes that have only a limited involvement with that hierarchy must be changed to match. For systems of any complexity, this is unsustainable.

Dynamic dispatching keeps the knowledge about what subtypes exist to the family of subtypes. A user of a `Car` doesn't want to write 11 different code paths just because there's `ElectricCar` and `InternalCombustionCar` and `HybridCar` etc. etc. He just wants to obtain a `Car` from a factory and have `car.start()` do the right thing without having to know what exact type of car he has. Type-specific overriding within the subclasses achieves exactly that.

Comment: Well, if I go back to my `Converted convert(...)` example, it  is still aware of all classes... Whether `instanceof` is used or not...