# Is this violating SRP? Data object with some additional info

Tags: design

I have data object's let say PersonDto (fields name, surname) and OrganizationDto (field name, type).

Then I have some common screen, showing such data, but screen title is something related to type of - Person/Organization.

The easiest way how to implement that functionality is to have field/constant in that class. Another approach would be to use some `instanceof` checks ([related to my previous question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/385177/method-overriding-as-a-substitution-for-instanceof-in-java/385180?noredirect=1#comment847061_385180)), the most complex (from my point of view) is to use [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), so at some point, there is one of methods called:

```
Visitor {
    accept(PersonDto dto) {
        return "Person";
    }
    accept(OrganizationDto dto) {
        return "Organization";
    }
}
```

Just now I realized, some magic with class name can be done (for example if DTO name is not one word I'd need to add space or something), but I do not like that approach at all.

Approach with additional field seems the most straighforward to me especially if I have common interface for DTOs, but it is breaking SRP in a sense, that class not only holds data, but knows something about screen/UI. I just prefer KISS more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a class meets the single responsibility principle?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154723/how-to-determine-if-a-class-meets-the-single-responsibility-principle)

Comment: Why is there a common screen in the first place? They look like different enough things to have their own UI, don't they?

Comment: ...simply because we can, sad I know. For example by serializing data to JSON all you have (as a result) is field name and it's value and you can have a generic screen for that. No need to write specific screen, no "additional" effort, quicker delivery, no space for errors...